# ubuntu USB drive dead?? no light, no feedback

Tags: usb-drive

I had Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS installed and booted from my Lexar 128GB usb 3.0 on a laptop without a hard drive. I was using it, it worked fine then I restarted my PC. After that I see my caps lock light blinking and on the screen there was orange brown background (it was like the ubuntu background) there were also horizontal lines something like this:

██████████████████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████████████████████████████
█████████████████████████████████████████████████
███████████████████████████████████████████████████████

and now my usb drive is dead. completely dead... no light, no feedback that its connected, not even saying that the drive is not supported or needs formating, nothing... I tried to connect it to my mac and even then there is nothing, It doesn't even show up in the disk utility. i also have another 4gb usb where there is a live ubuntu(its not really installed but its a bootable ubuntu usb that i can try and install ubuntu to other disk) and in there also it was nothing. Did ubuntu kill my usb drive .-. ?? from that 4gb usb, i opened it from "try without installing" and in there i also tried the boot-repair thingy but even that doesn't detect. Also remember, there is no light coming from the usb or anything happens when i connect it to my mac or that broken pc with "try without installing" ubuntu.
Any help is appreciated. also sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Sooouuundsss like a hardware failure. There should be codes for the blinking Caps Lock lights based on your manufacture. I would check those. Also, USBs aren't designed to have relatively heavy OSes, such as Ubuntu and Windows, to run as a full install from them. I recommend to disable things like journaling if you choose to make a full install again. Even more, Lexar isn't exactly a speedy or reliable USB brand, as well.

Comment: So it doesn't mean that it killed my usb completely just because i installed an OS on it ._.

Comment: You might've. USBs aren't exactly designed for such heavy lifting, especially relatively cheap consumer USBs. Please, check the Caps Lock codes for you computer to make sure you didn't burn anything out.

Comment: How do I check my caps lock codes? My PC doesn't even have a hard drive... And i hope my warranty covers  the stuff.

Comment: Who made your PC/what manufacturer?

Comment: Dell Inspiron 15 5000 series.

Comment: How many blinks does it blink when you turn on the computer? Can you access the BIOS?

Comment: Well my computer works perfectly fine with other bootable usb but the 128gb usb is dead. Yes i can access the BIOS and everything on the PC but the problem is that my USB is dead not the computer.

Comment: Then your USB is truly dead. I thought you said your PC was dead. At least that's not the case :)

Comment: Update: when i opened the case of the usb, i noticed a small light blink(the light only blinks for like 1/4 of a second) when i inserted it in my mac. Is it because the ext4 is not supported by mac??

Comment: Your Mac should at least detect the drive. Looks like a dead USB.